# Why are there so many questions closed as off-topic that have many upvotes?

Tags: support, questions, scope, closed-questions, upvotes

I've seen many questions on Stack Overflow that are closed as off-topic, saying that it's based on opinion, but there are tons of upvotes and WE LEARN stuff.

For example, this one:

[Docker for Windows error: "Hardware assisted virtualization and data execution protection must be enabled in the BIOS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684974/docker-for-windows-error-hardware-assisted-virtualization-and-data-execution-p)

Maybe it's time to reconsider this off-topic issue?

Comment: I could ask a question that's totally unrelated to a particular site, have it be interesting enough to generate votes and answers, and yet still have it closed as off-topic. I don't see this as being any different. The question and its answers will remain in the searchable database despite it being closed. So, it's not as if it's failing to act as a learning tool.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247337/popular-question-with-popular-answer-and-votes-for-closure

Comment: One word: *popularity*.  Questions can be popular, and still gather upvotes, but that still doesn't make it on-topic.  Upvotes can be a measure of utility, sure, but that still doesn't make them immune to curation.

Comment: "reconsider this off-topic issue" Are you referring to the specific question you linked or are you suggesting we should discuss the practice of closing questions that have lots of upvotes?

Comment: Aside popularity, there are some questions that were on-topic but after re-definitions aren't. There's also stuff that has slipped under the radar or otherwise not gotten enough attention to close. And yeah, popularity does play a factor. But that's NOT a reason to re-consider opening. If that was the case, SO would see more questions that're blatantly off-topic just because they get votes. As an example, the "programming jokes" question.

Comment: I am confused, when I view that question, there is no indication the question has been closed.

Comment: @SecurityHound It was closed on March 8th last year, went through re-open review a couple of times and was left closed, and was finally re-opened by Shog earlier today. [Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39684974/timeline).

Comment: @TylerH That's a good point, but probably not what you intended to mean. Off topic, duplicate, or any other question that gets closed, has an avenue of review in the form of votes - why would a question that is being closed have obtained upvotes instead of downvotes - the voting should be helpful to the outcome of the question's future.

Comment: @Rob Did you mean for that to be a reply to me or someone else? It doesn't seem like it makes sense as a reply to my comment.

Comment: @TylerH, to you. There's a reason it was reopened, and it was reflected in the voting.

Comment: @Rob Sorry, I don't follow. Shog reopened the question because he believed the question was on-topic. It had nothing to do with the number of votes the question had or has. You can read more on Shog's reasoning for reopening the question in his answer down below.

Comment: Ugh, that's not that big... look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication

Comment: "and we learn stuff" -> Maybe we should organize all this knowledge in some sort of documentation format. [Oh, wait!](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation)

Answer (score 19):

Closing and post score are orthogonal systems - the former is intended to block activity that would be wasted on questions that cannot or should not be answered, while the latter is intended to help folks find useful questions or avoid not-useful questions. Consider a ridiculously off-topic question such as, "how do I tighten chains on my automobile tires" - this could be a very useful and answerable question, yet still shouldn't be allowed here.

#### See also:

- [Old highly upvoted questions that don't follow current SO standards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306273/old-highly-upvoted-questions-that-dont-follow-current-so-standards)
- [Shouldn't "really popular" closed questions be re-assessed or re-opened automatically?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363473/shouldnt-really-popular-closed-questions-be-re-assessed-or-re-opened-automati?noredirect=1&lq=1)

That's the general purpose answer. Now, your specific example doesn't quite fit that. Yes, Docker is [a valid systems topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/docker) - but there's no evidence that's what the question here was concerned with, and it's every bit as likely that the asker was setting up a development environment on Windows. As Docker is also [a tool commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the question is on-topic and should be reopened - [if there's another reason for it to be closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380587/why-are-there-so-many-questions-closed-as-off-topic-but-they-have-many-upvotes/380589#380589), then that reason should be documented if it is re-closed.

I've reopened it.

#### See also:

- [How can I help a question to get reopened?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256445/how-can-i-help-a-question-to-get-reopened)
- [Getting questions reopened frequently feels impossible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366730/getting-questions-reopened-frequently-feels-impossible)

Comment: Just to be clear here (as someone who originally voted to close) Docker **installation** is an acceptable topic? I've closed many installation questions (not configuration related) for many tools as off-topic.

Comment: @Machavity:  Not sure I'm seeing the question describe installation.  The OP mentioned that things worked in the command line, but not the UI.  Sounds to me like it's *already* been installed.

Comment: @Makoto That's why I'm asking. If I got this wrong, I want to know for the future.

Comment: Feels like splitting hairs to me, @Machavity.

Comment: @Machavity If the question is about installing a *tool commonly used by programmers*, I would say it's on-topic. As long as the answer is more in-depth than "double click the .exe file" or whatever alternative for non-Windows OSes.

Comment: *" a tool commonly used by programmers"*- You missed the other part: *"and is ... a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"*.

Answer (score 10):

The number of upvotes on a question is only an indicator of the question's popularity, and isn't necessarily related to the question's scope.

For the example you provided, one can easily imagine that many people run into the same issue and find it helpful, which explains its very high popularity, specifically considering that it has a working solution. That's not a reason to say the question is on-topic on SO.

Another common case would be site's scope's changing. Software/library/framework recommendation used to be on-topic on SO, at which time a lot of such questions came up, among which a few went popular and therefore got many upvotes (some are still getting upvotes because people still find them useful). When the site's scope began to narrow, those questions were no longer on-topic and got closed gradually, but the votes didn't expire (and never will).

Comment: "When the site's scope began to narrow, those questions were no longer on-topic and got closed gradually" Important to note that this is also not a thing of the past--many tens of thousands of such questions are still open and are still being closed as they are found. This process will likely always continue.

Answer (score 5):

I wonder if this is a "Poor Man's Historical Lock" in effect on the question.

The amount of extra chatter in the answers indicates that perhaps the highest upvoted answer may *not* be all that great, or may not have stood the test of time.

It could also indicate that the Docker ecosystem has evolved enough that only certain Dockerfiles built in a certain way or running on a certain Docker version - **none of which are in the actual question** - could cause this problem.

Granted, the answer provided and upvoted may have been useful *back then*, but there's nothing empirical that can be related to *today* for users who also have to deal with this same Docker + Windows issue.

Comment: Possible, but this might be over-generous; none of the close voters have any activity in [tag:docker], so I kinda suspect this is a boring old case of folks not differentiating between Docker as a programming tool and Docker as infrastructure.

Comment: I decided to be optimistic and look at the circumstance as something potentially beneficial, @Shog9.  I'm starting to see that the close may be justified since there's no evidence that I can see that this *might* be applicable today.  I'm more familiar with Docker than Windows at this point though, but don't take my word for it...

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong about the problem, just that there's no evidence that this is why the question was closed.

Comment: @Shog9 is the problem really duplicatable with just the information in the question? The plethora of answers taking various stabs at different system configuration solutions tends to indicates that the question does not provide enough information to actually duplicate the problem.

Comment: @Makyen:  I believe *I'm* making that argument with my answer above...?

Comment: At this point, I doubt it matters @Makyen - the top answer gives what appears to be a reasonably thorough set of steps for diagnosing and correcting the problem based on the symptoms.

Comment: As far as useful back then vs. now, if upvotes on its timeline are any indication of that, it doesn't look like they've tapered off much since the answer was posted