# Where to ask Kubernetes server operational issues

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

As per *[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)*:

> Questions on professional server, networking, or related
>   infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless
>   they directly involve programming or programming tools.
>
> Professional system and network administrators, ask on Server Fault.

Although, there are several well-received questions on Stack Overflow that discuss Kubernetes infrastructure, core concepts, configuration, implementation, troubleshooting and some other subjects that are not even related to programming. Here are some examples:

- 357 Votes - [What's the difference between Apache's Mesos and Google's Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705201/whats-the-difference-between-apaches-mesos-and-googles-kubernetes)
- 150 Votes - [Pods stuck in Terminating status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453792/pods-stuck-in-terminating-status)
- 136 Votes - [Ingress vs Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079988/ingress-vs-load-balancer)
- 67 Votes - [Multiple environments (Staging, QA, production, etc) with Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43212836/multiple-environments-staging-qa-production-etc-with-kubernetes)

Right now I have a problem in Kubernetes/Docker/systemd that is causing millions of log lines and high CPU usage. This problem may overlap with Stack Overflow / Server Fault topics, as it involves some of server config files, ".yaml programming" and Kubernetes programming tools.

I know that [cross-posting is extremely discouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/03/22/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/). **So where is the best place to ask for help in problems like this one described above**? [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)? [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)? *Maybe even [DevOps (Beta)](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).*

Undoubtedly, questions on Stack Overflow have much more visibility due to the number of active users, so it's tempting to simply post there to find better answers quickly. There is a way to overcome this lack of visibility on another Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: You seem to be attracted to the number of users, but that is because Stack Overflow is home to questions about a plethora of very popular programming languages. You are likely not going to be helped by a Javascript or Python programmer. I mean the chance is always there, but the chance that they will actually see your question... slim at best, their attention will be going to other topics. Ask where the target audience of your question lives, and judging by what you've said so far which is mostly related to (nasty) Kubernetes runtime issues... Stack Overflow is not very likely going to be it.

Comment: I would place my bets on devops stackexchange. I know it's far less users but hey, more experienced with this type of stuff too.

Comment: I decided to post my question on Server Fault...In the case of it receives little attention (and eventually no answers), it's ok to move the question to Devops Stackexchange or it is considered disrespectful by the community? If it's ok, what's is the best way to move it to another site?

Comment: flag it for moderator attention asking them to migrate the question.

Comment: Re *"questions on Stack Overflow have much more visibility due to the number of active users, so it's tempting to simply post there to find better answers quickly."*: [Indeed it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56773158).

Comment: I think one of the better places for anything Linux-centric is [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). I would visit U&L.SE before SF because the folks on U&L.SE are just as knowledgeable and generally friendlier. Plus, SF has that requirement for professional admins (iirc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a long-running battle on SO. We prefer programming questions, but we allow the tertiary "programming tools" questions. I mean, [a Community Manager said most Docker questions are on-topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380590/2370483) so...

## Where do we draw the line?

- If your question involves tinkering with configuration files or using the server to program (or set up a programming environment) it's generally on-topic here. If you need proof, we have [apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache) as exhibit A.
- If your question involves installing the server software, operating system, network, etc, it's almost certainly better on [Server Fault](//serverfault.com) **provided you're using a professional system** (most Linux systems qualify, as well as Windows Server).
- If you're trying to install anything on your Windows **desktop** (i.e. How do I install [wamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wamp)?), then ask it on [Super User](//superuser.com)
- Virtually all Kubernetes/Docker/Chef/etc. (DevOps type stuff) is on-topic at [DevOps.SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)

## But I want to ask on Stack Overflow

The catch with asking here is you might not get an answer, the further into OS territory you go. In fact, go too far and we do [close questions like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56745738/cannot-able-to-use-internet-on-kali-linux-terminal). You *might* get an answer here, but understand that the other sites are more specialized, which means a smaller population, but also a smaller question pool. If you're in doubt, ask first on the smaller sites. Stack Overflow gets some 6000 questions a day. You might get lost in the shuffle.

Comment: While [Devops.SE] is very new and still sorting out its subject matter (last I checked anyway), questions about [Kubernetes](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) are likely to remain on topic there as that kind of technology is widely regarded as a tool to support the practice. Probably worth a mention as a potential option.

Comment: Many question in StackOverflow exist for K8s administration and has very high vote and active, for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/34848422/1539100

Comment: @sorosh_sabz I don't get why you're beating a dead horse here. The answer is it's generally on-topic here. I don't get why you feel the need to comment or edit your duplicate.