# Proposal for updated guidance for [kubernetes] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes) (K8S) tag wiki currently has the following usage guidance:

> KUBERNETES QUESTIONS MUST BE SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT. Configuration and deployment is off-topic here. A good rule of thumb is, if it happens outside the pod, it's probably off-topic. If it's about code running inside the pod, it's probably OK.

Firstly, the tone here strikes me as a little harsh. Why the all-caps (yelling)? And, "it's probably OK" - what's that supposed to mean? To me, this feels unnecessary and discouraging. Are we saying that if your question isn't SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT enough to us, the powers that be, we will still shoot it down?

Secondly, limiting the scope of the tag this way strikes me as outdated, given today's broad adoption of Kubernetes in the age of DevOps. Sure, questions about setting up your on-prem Kubernetes infrastructure should probably go to Server Fault. But excluding all questions related to "configuration and deployment", to me, feels too broad. A lot of problems fall into a gray area somewhere between creating and configuring the right set of K8S resources (including Deployments), throwing in a shell command or two (so.. is that SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT?), or actually changing the code that's running in a container on a pod.

Here's my proposal for an updated usage guidance:

> Please note that questions related to Kubernetes server infrastructure, for example related to setting up and managing an on-prem Kubernetes cluster, should be asked on Server Fault. Scope of this tag are questions related to running your workloads on an existing Kubernetes cluster.

Thoughts?

Comment: The caps lock is just for emphasis, to bring people's attentions to the most important bit, since tag descriptions can't have Markdown formatting. I've seen this done across the network, particularly with obsolete tags such as those for ID questions.

Comment: *"given today's broad adoption of Kubernetes in the age of DevOps"* if it's about DevOps, have the  it would be better off on [DevOps.se].

Comment: @F1Krazy ok understood. To me, it would still feel kinda harsh even if it was emphasized with *markdown*.

Comment: @Larnu really difficult to draw a line here, IMHO. You might not even know yet by the time you're asking the question.

Comment: It is a legal thing. People kept saying that they didn't read the fine print. So the essential parts are NOW IN CAPITALS SO YOU CAN'T CLAIM IT WAS IN FINE PRINT. Same here. Nobody bloody reads the excerpt. Making it shout, maybe they hear it above the rush of excitement of finally posting a question.

Comment: Who, exactly, is the victim of this alleged harshness? No victim, no foul.

Comment: Related: [Where to ask Kubernetes server operational issues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386504/2821954). The scope has been discussed and clarified there.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk literally anyone reading that page

Comment: @AndrewT. yes, but that was 2.5 years ago, which is about half an eternity in tech, in particular in the cloud native space.

Comment: That a question could be asked on Server Fault doesn't make it off-topic here. It is only off-topic here if we declare it to be off-topic here. And questions can only be closed as off-topic here when they are actually off-topic here, not because you think they could/should be asked somewhere else. So, your proposed rewording is dangerously incorrect. Yes, only questions specifically related to software development are on-topic for SO. This means that the *vast majority* of questions about Kubernetes are off-topic here. Calling that out in all caps to increase the odds it's seen seems useful.

Answer (score 12):

> To me, this feels unnecessary and discouraging. Are we saying that if your question isn't SPECIFICALLY RELATED TO SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT enough to us, the powers that be, we will still shoot it down?

... Yes. We are saying that, and yes—those who are able to discern whether a question is on- or off-topic according to the guidance found in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic will do what they can with their site privileges to "shoot it down" (flag for closure, or close-vote with the appropriate close reason).

Note: The phrase "The powers that be" seems to indicate a stigma with [the way we do "moderation" on Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/). We are largely community-moderated. We don't have tyrannical mods. Our real "mods" (see [`help/site-moderators`](/help/site-moderators)) do tons of invisible (and largely thankless) work to keep the community healthy. Our mods are elected by the community and for the community. A lot of the moderation activities are carried out by regular users with [their site privileges](/help/privileges).

If a DevOps question doesn't fit here, it might fit on the devops.stackexchange.com site. Sadly and surprisingly, at the time of this writing, [their `/help/on-topic` page](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) only seems to contain the cookie-cutter text. I've written [a feature request on their meta site asking if they'd please add guidance to their `/help/on-topic` page](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/390/38667). Interestingly, when I was browsing their meta site, I also saw this post: [Proposal for mass-migration from StackOverflow?](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/q/380/38667).