# Why was this question about debugging an Android device closed and locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, historical-lock

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp) asks how to connect an Android device to your computer for debugging purposes. While it is a hardware-related question, it's one that's only likely to come up in the context of development – there may be other reasons to connect a device to your computer, but the question specifically asks about using Android Debug Bridge. If this is off-topic, then so should the countless questions about installing IDEs, configuring browser debugging, and any other questions about setting up development tools.

So why is it locked?

Comment: It was pointed out to me as being off-topic, similar to another off-topic question. Upon review, it did not look to me like it was about software development, so I closed it. The reason it has a historical lock is merely because it looked like it had some value that would be lost by deleting it. I'm happy to reconsider if an Android expert wants to make an argument here and/or based on community consensus.

Comment: Looking at the question it doesn't appear to be about tools primarily used in programming, the adb just appears to be a shell, where you can install and debug and run commands, like backups, and other arbitrary tasks... So why would this be on topic when non-programming shell questions are off-topic?

Comment: So when I need to debug a program on my phone and I can't get it to connect to my debugger, I'm supposed to go...where, exactly? How is that not a programming problem?

Comment: *Physically* connecting your device to a debugger sounds like a hardware problem. Not much software can do for you there.

Comment: Figuring out which pins to connect on each end is a hardware problem. Figuring out what to do with the signals at either end is most definitely a software problem. Some of us learning programming that way. It was very rewarding once the two devices started talking and making noise. To say it's "just a hardware issue" would make programming itself a "hardware issue" because it required muscles hitting keyboards.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I don't understand your position after viewing the answers. There was a ton of apparently useful reponse to this question. True, it could have been improve with some OP examples of failing efforts at coding, but there did seem to be a lot of specific coding suggestions.

Comment: @Cody I think it's a bit of an edge case. ADB is really only meant for development (and debugging ofc), but setting up an ADB over IP connection doesn't really seem like it counts as using the tool itself. Either way, it's a better question for Android.se or SuperUser.

Comment: @IRTFM The answers do not make a question on-topic, no matter how good they are. I *did* review the answers, and that's why I chose to apply a historical lock to the question, instead of deleting it. None of the answers themselves appear to have any code (terminal commands are not code), and I'm certainly not one of those people laboring under the mistaken impression that every question needs to include a failed coding attempt.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Please use the *answer box* below to add your justifications why you think this is (or is not) a programming question, and should therefore be re-opened (or not). Aside from the fact that this is not what comments are meant for, I simply won't see all of your responses and cannot properly respond to them if they are posted as comments.

Comment: @codyGray I would dispute the position that terminal commands are not code. Those are commands to a specific program within the OS. Most of my programming is done oat the console level. I then take the text from successful effort and use it as components in packages. Those are commands that can be encoded into an application which appears to be the hope of the OP.

Comment: @CodyGray: You should leave your answer (from your first comment) as an answer instead of a comment ;)

Answer (score 5):

I think this should be unlocked and reopened. I'm not terribly keen on *system* support questions, but I've used [adb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adb) when I wrote an app many years ago, and Android Debug Bridge(ADB) is definitely a programming tool. That changes things a great deal. Last year I voted to close [this Docker question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684974/docker-for-windows-error-hardware-assisted-virtualization-and-data-execution-p) which was later [reopened by Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380590)

> Yes, Docker is a valid systems topic - but there's no evidence that's what the question here was concerned with, and it's every bit as likely that the asker was setting up a development environment on Windows. As Docker is also a tool commonly used by programmers, the question is on-topic and should be reopened - if there's another reason for it to be closed, then that reason should be documented if it is re-closed.

This seems to fall into the same category. I would not vote to close that question since it is about configuring a programming tool (even if the answers seem like they are more fit for Super User).

Comment: I concur with this answer (was going to write my own but this one captures what I wanted to say, too).  Being able to debug running apps is common in Android, and being able to do it over TCP is actually a convenience thing that newer versions of Android allow you to take advantage of.

Comment: @Makoto but, that's not all that ADB does.

Answer (score -2):

It's said that to illustrate something, we should go to the extremes, so, let’s go to the absolute extreme: programming on Microsoft Word.

If I'm coding language X, and I have any problem, I can ask any* question about language X, since everything I do with language X is a programming problem. But since I'm using Microsoft Word to write said code, is Microsoft Word also on topic? It would be very uphill to argue that because I use Microsoft Word for programming, it becomes automatically a programming question.

Instead, I believe we should focus on the *task* that is being done with the tool. Saying that *because I use X tool, it's automatically a programming question* isn't very reasonable rule of thumb to go by. Remember, ADB is also a tool commonly used to change/modify the OS on Android devices (one could argue which is more prominent use, but I would like that we sidestep that), so going by "I used ADB for programming, therefore is a programming tool" is too naive. Also, it would argue that everyone that uses ADB is a programmer, which is also naive.

As said in the beginning, I prefer to use *the task* to be the benchmark. Is the task the question is about a software development task or it's just another task that people not doing software development would ask about?

* We are discussing topically here, this doesn't preclude other quality standards to be considered a question that can be asked on the site.

Comment: If I use my IDE for editing system config files, does that make questions about installing IDEs off-topic? Saying that you should use the task as the benchmark seems to go against the site's precedent for tool questions.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery that's a problem of grammar. I read it as (A|B|C)&&X. In other words it has to be "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". So, no. Installing software on your system is not a problem unique to software development, no matter what "software" you are installing.

Comment: ADB is a programming tool, full stop. That's what it was built for - the initials stand for Android Debug Bridge - and *also* what the asker in question is looking to use it for. The other use you cite came about primarily due to the work of folks on another developer site providing instructions based on the tooling they had handy - it'd be like setting up your documentation team with VSCode. Which happens. And VSCode questions are still firmly on-topic unless there's compelling evidence that you're using it for something that's entirely unrelated. Maybe trying to install a Snake game plugin.

Comment: @Shog9 "Android Debug Bridge (adb) is a versatile command-line tool that **lets you communicate with a device**. The adb command facilitates a **variety of device actions**, such as **installing and debugging apps**, and it provides access to a Unix shell that you can use to run a variety of commands on a device" [source](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) Android developer page doesn't agree.

Comment: Also can take screenshots, @Braiam... And a bunch of other stuff. Kind of a grabbag of tools that come in handy when debugging.

Comment: @Shog9 yeah, but your comment saying that "is a programming tool" is like saying that it's **only** a programming tool. It would be like saying that a swiss army knife is only a knife and that it is a weapon, *full stop*. But the tool is as used outside of programming (I think I used it to remove crap from an phone), so in this case, only saying adb is on topic is misguided at best. It would be more accurate to say that using adb for programming is on topic, the mere use of adb doesn't make your question on topic.

Comment: It's a multifunction tool, yes. Just like every IDE and many if not most debuggers. That neither guarantees topicality nor suggests any particular likelihood of a question being off-topic. Given the purpose of combining these functions *is* on-topic, I suggest assuming topicality by default.

Comment: @Shog9 I go the other way. For me, not the tool, but the task defines topically.

Comment: The task in question is "attempting to debug an application on a Motorola Droid". Programming tool + programming task. One should be sufficient, and both are present.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not talking about this particular question. That's probably why we are talking past each other. I'm challenging the other answer argument.